# Java- Difference in compression for single thread and multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, compression, gzip

So I'll preface this by saying that my multithreaded program fails to output something that gzip can successfully decompress, so there might be other issues. But what I've noticed is that the compression size of each block for single thread and multithread is radically different.

In my single threaded run, I have a GZIPOutputStream(System.out, true) with SYNC_FLUSH set. I read from system.in continually until my buffer is full.

```
GZIPOutputStream compressor = new GZIPOutputStream(System.out, true);
bytesRead = inBytes.read(buff,0,BLOCK_SIZE);
....
while(bytesRead != -1)
{
    offset += bytesRead;
    if (offset == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        compressor.write(buff,0,offset);
        compressor.flush();
        offset = 0;
    }

    if((bytesRead=inBytes.read(buff,offset,BLOCK_SIZE-offset)) == -1) {
        compressor.write(buff,0,offset);
        compressor.finish();
    }
}
compressor.close();
```

As you can see, after a have a full buffer, I tell compressor to write to output, and then I call flush. The assures that I force it to compress and flush out any remaining output, so when it goes to write again, it doesn't have any left over data in the buffer.

So it's quite similar to as if your original input had been that length to begin with (so each block is it's own individual stream).

So in my multithreaded program, instead of having one GZIPOutputStream write and flush, I just have a bunch of threads that each have their own GZIPOutputStream. So basically, replace that part with a call to a thread

```
List<Future<byte[]>> results = new ArrayList<Future<byte[]>>();
bytesRead = inBytes.read(buff,0,BLOCK_SIZE);

while(bytesRead != -1)
{
    offset += bytesRead;
    if (offset == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        results.add(exec.submit(new workerThread(buff,offset)));
        offset = 0;
    }

    if((bytesRead=inBytes.read(buff,offset,BLOCK_SIZE-offset)) == -1) {
        results.add(exec.submit(new workerThread(buff,offset)));
    }
}
```

Where I just pass the buffer to them to compress. All my threads do is

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private byte[] finalOut;
....
public byte[] call() {
    try{
        GZIPOutputStream compress = new GZIPOutputStream (bOut, true);
        compress.write(input,0,size);
        compress.flush();
        compress.close();
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
     }
     finalOut = bOut.toByteArray();
     return finalOut;
 }
```

I think all I've literally done is given the compression job to the threads. I didn't change anything else. However, when I run my multi-threaded program and hexdump the result, I noticed that each block usually differs a lot between the two programs. I used a small buffer and small input so it was more easily read.

I get a crc error with my multithreaded program, which means at least that gzip recognizes the format and begins decompressing. It's just that when it's done, the final result doesn't match what it expected from the CRC (such as the size of the decompressed output and such).

I'm honestly not sure why this happens. I would have expected some much more obvious error, but this one seems so random. It's definitely compressing. And the first few bytes between the single threaded and multithreaded program (after the header of course) are often the same, so I don't think I'm concatenating out of order (plus the executor.get() function should handle that).

I'm just stumped. I know gzip can decompress concatenated streams. I literally split my input in half and output it separately then combined them in my singlethread program and it decompressed just fine.

For the record, I just tried it on a file with 328 "A" characters, so it's not very large. The GZIPOutputStream's hexdump for a single thread is

```
0000000 8b1f 0008 0000 0000 0000 7472 581c 0000
0000010 0000 ffff 681a 0004 0000 ffff 21a2 02e2
0000020 0000 ff00 03ff a800 5bff 5c79 0001 0000
```

And for multithreaded it's

```
0000000 8b1f 0008 0000 0000 0000 7472 19a4 22e0
0000010 1146 0000 ff00 03ff 7500 5f6c 80d1 0000
0000020 1f00 088b 0000 0000 0000 a200 e221 4622
0000030 0011 0000 ffff 0003 6c75 d15f 0080 0000
0000040 8b1f 0008 0000 0000 0000 21a2 02e2 0000
0000050 ff00 03ff 8a00 193b 5c21 0000 0000
```

They're pretty different.

Wow this ended up being really long. Sorry about that. Just really puzzled and stuck.

Comment: Can you provide an example which can be run? It looks like you share your buffer between threads, which means the content is probably quite random then. And even more, I do not think that this is a good idea to create a new GZIP for every part.

Comment: ok, if gzip satisfies unzip(gzip(a+b))=unzip(gzip(a) + gzip(b)) for two strings a,b then you can use new gzip instances for every part. I did not find any references from a quick search, but from a logical viewpoint it would make sense. Because gzip is used a lot for chunked encoding, like for http.

Answer (score 1):

The `flush()` and `finish()` calls are not needed.  `close()` will finish, and the `flush()` calls just add unnecessary empty blocks to the deflate stream.  Since you don't need `flush()`, you don't need to set `syncFlush` true, since it won't do anything.

Making a single large gzip stream and making a bunch of small gzip streams will of course produce quite different results.  Every gzip stream has an overhead of 18 bytes for the header and trailer.  With the tiny blocks you're using, that overhead completely dominates the result.

There is a big fat bug in your threaded example.  While the unthreaded example compressed 328 'A's, the threaded example has 'A's and line feed characters (decimal 10) mixed together.  Maybe you should start without even trying to compress, and see if you can break up some input (real text, not just a sequence of identical characters), send the chunks to threads, have the threads do nothing to the data at all, and then correctly reconstruct the original input.  Once you can do that, then come back.

Answer (score 0):

To start somewhere:

> They're pretty different.

If my assumption from the comment holds (gzip satisfies unzip(gzip(a+b))=unzip(gzip(a) + gzip(b)) for two strings a,b), then this is expected behavior.

According to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-6), every gzip call will write a header. In [Java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.java#GZIPOutputStream.writeHeader%28%29):

```
private void writeHeader() throws IOException {
    out.write(new byte[] {
                  (byte) GZIP_MAGIC,        // Magic number (short)
                  (byte)(GZIP_MAGIC >> 8),  // Magic number (short)
                  Deflater.DEFLATED,        // Compression method (CM)
                  0,                        // Flags (FLG)
                  0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                  0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                  0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                  0,                        // Modification time MTIME (int)
                  0,                        // Extra flags (XFLG)
                  0                         // Operating system (OS)
              });
}
```

[GZIP_MAGIC is 8b1f:](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.java#GZIPOutputStream.0GZIP_MAGIC)

```
private final static int GZIP_MAGIC = 0x8b1f;
```

[And Deflater.DEFLATED is 8:](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/zip/Deflater.java#Deflater.0DEFLATED)

```
public static final int DEFLATED = 8;
```

A header will start with:
`1f 8b 80 ...`
You can clearly see this part in your output (byte-swapped). The header starts again for every new gzip part. So your chunked output must be greater in length than your normal output.

About the multithreaded issues: I need a complete sample to see what is happening.